cannot import name 'execute' from 'qiskit'
I'm new to quantum computing and am currently working on building a quantum multiplication calculator. I've installed all the necessary packages, but I'm still encountering an ImportError. Here are the details:
What I've Done So Far:
Installed Qiskit:
I installed Qiskit using pip:
pip install qiskit
The Problem:
Despite these steps, when I try to import Qiskit in my script, I get an ImportError:
import qiskit from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
The error message is:
ImportError: No module named 'qiskit' 
(https://i.sstatic.net/53YyrakH.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/M645zL4p.png)
I have installed all the packages said in official site(https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/start/install)

The error message in your description is No module named 'qiskit'. The error message in your image is Cannot import name 'excute' from 'qiskit'. So which error do you need help with?

You are getting the error Cannot import name 'excute' from 'qiskit' because qiskit.execute function has been deprecated in qiskit>1.0.0. Instead of using execute you can now use transpile and run as explained in Qiskit 1.0's migration guide for execute:
Your current (deprecated) import
from qiskit import execute

Should be replaced with
from qiskit import transpile

And now instead of using execute like this:
job = execute(circuit, backend)

You should use transpile and run as follows:
new_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)
job = backend.run(new_circuit)

Assuming you have your backend initialized, e.g.,
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

Hope this helps!
